# Alignment at the inequality in a system of linear inequalities

Tags: align, arrays

I have a system of linear inequalities (in the variables `x` and `y`) that I have aligned at the inequality.  There is no inter-line spacing. If I had expressions that were `x - y < 3`, there would have been enough inter-line spacing.  In the following code, fractions in display-mode in each inequality of the system are to be tyepset.  How do I get "the proper" inter-line spacing?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\left\{ \begin{array}{r @{{}\leq{}} l}
y - \dfrac{2}{k} \, x                   & 0 \\
\dfrac{1}{k} \, x - \dfrac{1}{2} \, y   & -1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The interline spacing in an array is controlled by the macro \arraystretch.  The spacing is constant for the entire array, and therefore pays no attention to each row size.

Comment: @John Kormylo  What would you suggest for this display?  I may have other `array` environments in the file containing the code in this post that do not need any "stretching."  How would I use the "stretching" only for the current `array` environment?

Comment: Put \def\arraystretch{2.5} inside the align (or equation).  It will reset at the end of the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you meaning something like this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % amsart loads amsmath

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
  y - \frac{2}{k}x            &\le 0 \\[1ex]
\dfrac{1}{k}x - \dfrac{1}{2}y &\le -1
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `align` for single line displays, only for alignment displays.

On the other hand, I don't think you should align the relation signs.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{dcases}
  y - \frac{2}{k}x              \le 0 \\
  \dfrac{1}{k}x - \dfrac{1}{2}y \le -1
\end{dcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the display that I want.  Why doesn't the code I provide give this nice inter-line spacing?

Comment: @Adelyn Because you're using the wrong tool. `;-)`

Comment: I see that you used an `aligned` environment and provided further separation between the lines with `[1ex]`.

Comment: You say not to use `align`  for single-line displays but only for alignment displays.  What is a "single-line display" and what is an "alignment display"?

Comment: @Adelyn In this case you have a single object in the display (which is a two line object itself, but it's not important). Use `align` only if you have multiple lines at the outer level.

Comment: By the way, is there any reason you removed my use of `\left\{ ... \right.` and replaced it with `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}`?

Comment: @Adelyn It's handier, isn't it? But it also adds some spacing between lines.